# perl: how to remove particular word or pattern in between two patterns

Tags: regex, perl, multiline, text-processing

I want to remove some words within two patterns using perl

The following is my text

```
..........

QWWK jhjh  kljdfh jklh jskdhf jkh PQXY
lhj ah jh sdlkjh PQXY jha slkdjh 
PQXY jh alkjh ljk
kjhaksj dkjhsd KWWQ
hahs dkj h PQXY
.........
```

Now i want to remove all `PQXY` words which only lies between the two patterns
`^QWWK` and `KWWQ$`

I know how to replace the whole thing inbetween the two patterns by the following command

```
perl -0777pe 's/^QWWK(?:(?!QWWK|KWWQ).)*KWWQ$/sometext/gms' filename
```

Also note that `^QWWK(?:(?!QWWK|KWWQ).)*KWWQ$` this pattern only matches those where there is no QWWK and KWWQ inbetween.

Comment: Do you care about preserving the specific whitespace between words?  If not, an inner loop over `split` results would let you use the range operator word-by-word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach you've tried, with the little more needed for it to work

```
perl -0777 -wpe's{^(QWWK (?:(?!QWWK|KWWQ).)*? KWWQ)$}{ $1 =~ s/PQXY//gr }egmsx' file
```

The `/e` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) makes it evaluate the replacement side as code, and we run a regex there.

In that regex the `/r` modifier makes it return the changed string (and not change the original, what allows us to run it on `$1` which is read-only).

The requirement that the `^QWWK`-to-`KWWQ$` block of text not contain either of these phrases is satisfied by the code above but a few comments may be helpful.

We *don't* need the non-greedy `.*?` since `.*` (following the negative lookahead) actually stops at `KWWQ$`.  But this is tricky to ascertain, and `.*` just has the potential to slurp up *all* up to the very last `KWWQ`, including all other possible blocks and any text between them.

Altogether I just find `.*?` safer and simpler, specially as that *is* what is needed.

The `QWWK` must start a line (it's given with `^` in the question) to be a marker for a block. If an extra `QWWK` is found inside the block then the whole block does not match. But, if that "extra" `QWWK` inside happens to be on the beginning of a line then

- what would've been a block doesn't match, since there is `QWWK` inside
- a block is in fact matched beginning with *that* `QWWK`

I use `/x` above so to be able to space out the pattern for readability.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the range operator:

```
perl -pe 's/PQXY//g if /^QWWK/ .. /KWWQ$/'
```

Comment: Also i want to satisfy the condition of (?!QWWK|KWWQ).) (i.e there will not be any QWWK and KWWQ inbetween

Comment: Could you add this specific case into the input sample?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
To replace PQXY only if QWWK or KWWQ are NOT present between ^QWWK and KWWQ$ give this a try:

```
perl -pe 'if (/^QWWK/ .. /KWWQ$/) {s/PQXY//g if ! /.+QWWK/ && !/KWWQ.+/}' filename
```

I'm sure it can be cleaned up / golfed, however I think it will give you what you are asking for.

Comment: Also i want to satisfy the condition of `(?!QWWK|KWWQ).)` (i.e there will not be any QWWK and KWWQ inbetween

Comment: I tested it with the multiline example data in the question. Seems to work for multiline.

Comment: If you want to exclude the inner QWWK | KWWQ across multiple lines, you would need to read the entire file first. The  -p command line option will only read a line at the time, so the  /m regex option is not really used and thus no multiline match.

Comment: assuming instead of PQXY i want to remove the new line how to do that.

Comment: `s/\R//g` woud remove newlines in a string containing multiple newlines

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this may be clearer with other tools than regexes.  The following does collapse any whitespace between words to a single space.

**Input** `qwwk.txt` (with one line added)

```
..........

QWWK jhjh  kljdfh jklh jskdhf jkh PQXY
lhj ah jh sdlkjh PQXY jha slkdjh
PQXY jh alkjh ljk
kjhaksj dkjhsd KWWQ
hahs dkj h PQXY
.........

KWWQ in mid line doesn't trigger: QWWK a PQXY b KWWQ c QWWK d PQXY e KWWQ
```

**Command** `perl qwwk.pl qwwk.txt`

**Output**

```
..........

QWWK jhjh kljdfh jklh jskdhf jkh
lhj ah jh sdlkjh jha slkdjh
jh alkjh ljk
kjhaksj dkjhsd KWWQ
hahs dkj h PQXY
.........

KWWQ in mid line doesn't trigger: QWWK a PQXY b KWWQ c QWWK d PQXY e KWWQ
```

**Program** `qwwk.pl`

```
use strict; use warnings;
while(<>) {             # for each line
    my @out;
    my @words=split;    # get its words

    for my $i (0..$#words) {
        my $w=$words[$i];
        my $active = ($i==0 && $w eq q(QWWK)) .. ($i==$#words && $w eq q(KWWQ));
            # Keep track of where we are.  See notes below.
        push @out, $w unless $active and ($w eq q(PQXY));
            # Save words we want to keep
    } #foreach word

    print join(q( ), @out), qq(\n);     # Print the words we saved
} #foreach line
```

The key is that the flip-flop (`..`) operator in the `$active= FOO .. BAR` assignment keeps its state regardless of what is happening around it.  It will be true from 
a `QWWK` at the start of a line (`($i==0 && $w eq q(QWWK))`) to a `KWWQ` at the end of the line (`($i==$#words && $w eq q(KWWQ))`), regardless of how many lines intervene.

**As a one-liner**

```
perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -ne 'my @out; my @words=split; for my $i (0..$#words) { my $w=$words[$i]; my $active = ($i==0 && $w eq q(QWWK)) .. ($i==$#words && $w eq q(KWWQ)); push @out, $w unless $active and ($w eq q(PQXY)); } print join(q( ), @out), qq(\n);' qwwk.txt
```

The difference here is that `-n` provides the `while(<>){}` loop, so that's not included in the `-e` script.  (Plus, now you know why I used `q()` and `qq()` in the standalone program ;) .)

Comment: I will try this. I have to understand it a little bit